# How to request a Facebook user's Platform Mode through PHP?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I'm using OAuth 2 and PHP to let users authorize an app with Facebook. How to check if their [Platform Mode](https://m.facebook.com/privacy/touch/apps/) is enabled? (It can be turned *OFF* to block all 3rd party apps.)

Comment: I'm not sure that you can... Normally if the mode is off, then the user can't authorize apps in general. If you have already authorized at least one app, you can't change the mode (I tried, to see what happens). I think that Facebook takes care of that, not your app. I can't swear though.